# Conditional statement within an append output

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

Is it possible to do something like this

```
$( "#till__tablepanel_table_"+tablenumber ).append( "<span>"+if (variable == 1) { writeHere }+"</span>" );
```

I cannot seem to get this working. Example: How would i `writeHere` if the conditions were true?

Comment: Was just curious to know if there was a way to do like this as you can with PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a ternary if statement for that:

```
.append( "<span>" + (variable == 1 ? writeHere : "" ) + "</span>" );
```

Comment: ah, excellent, so it is possible, thats what i was curious about. I know about preliminary conditional statements, but wanted to know if it was possible in the midst of a line. Thanks!